# Can I check the current value in an IPython magic command (%xmode)?

Tags: ipython

I want to check the current value of a magic command `%xmode`. The available mode is `Context`, `Plain`, and `Verbose`.

If you just type in `%xmode`, then it automatically switches to the next value. Certainly, you can know which value it was set to, but it is a pain to run the same command two more times to set it back to the original value.

So is it possible to only chech the value, without changing it?

Comment: Did you get a chance to try my answer?

Comment: @AmitSingh Yes, and sorry for being late to respond...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can run the following line to get the current `xmode` from an IPython terminal

```
get_ipython().config['InteractiveShell']['xmode']
```